# Castle Windsor "Late bound" components

Tags: c#, .net, nhibernate, inversion-of-control, castle-windsor

I've got several components registered in my container and Windsor can inject them without problems.
Now I've added a new registration for NHibernate ISessionFactory in this way:

```
foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> _tenantItem in _contextWrapper.TenantsConnectionStrings)
        {
            var config = Fluently.Configure()
                .Database(
                    MsSqlConfiguration.MsSql2008
                    .UseOuterJoin()
                    .ConnectionString(_tenantItem.Value)
                    .FormatSql()
                    .ShowSql()
                )

                .ExposeConfiguration(ConfigurePersistence)
                .ProxyFactoryFactory(typeof(ProxyFactoryFactory))
                .BuildConfiguration();

            Kernel.Register(
                Component.For<ISessionFactory>()
                    .UsingFactoryMethod(config.BuildSessionFactory)
                    .Named(_tenantItem.Key)
                    .LifestyleTransient()
                    );
        }
```

Now if I try to inspect my container I see:

[image]

Component Implementation is "Late bound" and Windsor won't inject it.

What's wrong? What I can check?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It probably doesn't like that you are creating your config instance at runtime.

You would be better off creating a proper class for your config, registering it with the container, and using that to create ISessionFactory instance.

```
public class MySessionFactoryBuilder : IMySessionFactoryBuilder
{
    private FluentConfiguration _fluentConfiguration = null;

    public MySessionFactoryBuilder()
    {
    }

    void Initialize(string connectionStringKey)
    {
        IPersistenceConfigurer persistenceConfigurer = null;

        persistenceConfigurer = MsSqlConfiguration.MsSql2008
                .UseOuterJoin()
                .ConnectionString(connectionStringKey)
                .FormatSql()
                .ShowSql()
                ;

        _fluentConfiguration = Fluently.Configure()
            .Database(persistenceConfigurer)
            .ExposeConfiguration(ConfigurePersistence)
            .ProxyFactoryFactory(typeof(ProxyFactoryFactory))
            .BuildConfiguration()
            ;
    }

    public ISessionFactory BuildSessionFactory(string connectionStringKey)
    {
        Initialize(connectionStringKey);
        return _fluentConfiguration.BuildSessionFactory();
    }

}
```

You can have that registered normally. Then you register multiple ISessionFactory, one per tenant, in your installer loop:

```
foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> _tenantItem in _contextWrapper.TenantsConnectionStrings)
{

    container.Register(
    Component.For<ISessionFactory>()
        .UsingFactoryMethod(k => k.Resolve<MySessionFactoryBuilder>().BuildSessionFactory(_tenantItem.Value))
        .Named(_tenantItem.Key),

    Component.For<ISession>()
        .UsingFactoryMethod(k => k.Resolve<ISessionFactory>().OpenSession())
        .Named(_tenantItem.Key + "-nhsession")
        .LifeStyle.Transient
        );

}
```

Note, i registered ISession transient, but not ISessionFactory. Normally you want to keep your ISessionFactory as long as possible, as it is expensive to create.

I haven't tested it, but i'm guessing that will resolve it, as the implementation of the session factory builder is known at compile-time.

Answer (score 3):

There are two separate and unrelated questions here so let me answer them in turn.

*"late bound"* as the component description says, merely means Windsor doesn't know the implementation type of your `ISessionFactory` statically. This is not a reason for concern.

It's simply up to the factory method you specify, `config.BuildSessionFactory()` in your case, to build the instance and it may not even be the same type every time.

One might implement the factory method like:

```
public ISessionFactory BuildSessionFactory()
{
   if (Today == DayOfWeek.Friday)
   {
      return new BeerOClockSessionFactory();
   }
   return SomeOtherSessionFactory();
}
```

This is fine and normal.

The other question you hinted at, indicates that you may be experiencing unexpected behaviour where the dependency on the `ISessionFactory` is not satisfied as expected.

Sadly, unless you explain more about it, share what sort of errors you're seeing I don't think there's much I can help other than to say "it should be working".

Also while we're at it, I wholeheartedly agree with @raulg that making session factory transient doesn't sound like a particularly good idea.

Comment: Could it be that the config (FluentConfiguration) is not actually registered with the container? Calling it's factory method Fluently.Configure() would be like creating a new component not managed by the container?

Comment: no. it doesn't matter if it's registered. I never register it

Comment: @KrzysztofKozmic would you mind having a look at this : 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25064516/dependency-injection-lifestyle-service-shared-instance-between-2-instances-of?noredirect=1#comment39052582_25064516